# hide index.php with short link in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I replace `example.com/index.php?p=25&nav=left` with  `example.com/page/25/left` and if possible I also want to block access to my index.html file.

if someone entered `example.com/index.php` redirect them to `welcome.php`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your web_root/htaccess

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$ 
RewriteRule .* /welcome.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ /index.php?p=$1&nav=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ welcome.php [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^page/(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&nav=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

It is important to use `THE_REQUEST` in first rule since that variable doesn't change with application of other rules to avoid redirect loop.